# cake bake shell script fails (after cakephp2 => cakephp3 migration)

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently in the process of migrating an app from 2 => 3. Whenever I run cake/bake I get this error:

```
Exception: Shell class for "-working" could not be found. in [/Users/david/Sites/otherland/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 328]
```

When I look at the parameters that are given to the ShellDispatcher I see this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /Users/david/Sites/otherland/app/bin/cake.php
    [1] => -working
    [2] => /Users/david/Sites/otherland/app
    [3] => bake
)
```

Obviously the param with index 1 is the problem. I am not actively typing "-working" into the shell. I have no idea where this might come from. Does anybody know where this might originate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not replaced the file `app/bin/cake` (for windows users that would be `app/bin/cake.bat`). There are some small changes in theses file from cake 2 to 3 and they need to be replaced. (Get them here https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/bin)

Edit: The cakephp upgrade-tool (https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade) has a task (`skeleton`) that copies the aforementioned files and more. I haven`t tried it, but this seems like a good way to deal with the problem.

Comment: Might I advise that you use composer to generate a cake 3 project and bake to generate new models, and then move code over from the cake 2 project manually. This allows you to start with free unit tests which you can use to verify functionality as you go. It takes longer yes, but you get better results at the end.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini That is certainly a way, but I chose to use the 3.x Upgrade Tool and than you have to replace the files mentioned manually.

Comment: I actually forgot there was an upgrade tool. If this is something that the tool has missed. You should open an issue on the GitHub project to alert the team as it sounds like something it should do.

Comment: I just looked at the code of the upgrade tool. There is a task that copies the mentioned files - the skeleton task. My mistake seems to have been that I did not run that task. I will update my answer accoringly.